# Working with morning star to try to get stock data, but ['Adj Close'] isn't working

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I was just trying to get data for a stock analysis project, and ran into a problem with Adj Close. Whenever I run a program with ['Adj Close'] in it I get an error with a bunch of stuff, but at the bottom it says Key Error:'Adj  Close'. I have my code right here, and was wondering if I could get some feedback.

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web

style.use('ggplot')
##start = dt.datetime(2018,3,3)
##end = dt.datetime.now()

##df = web.DataReader('TSLA', 'morningstar', start, end)
##df.reset_index(inplace=True)
##df.set_index('Date',inplace=True)
##df = df.drop('Symbol',axis=1)
##df.to_csv('tsla.csv')
df = pd.read_csv('tsla.csv', parse_dates=True, index_col=0)
####print(df.head())
##df['Adj Close'].plot()
##plt.show()

 df['100mma'] = df['Adj Close'].rolling(window=100, min_periods=0).mean()
##df.dropna(inplace=True)
print(df.Head())

ax1  = plt.subplot2grid((6,1), (0,0), rowspan=5, colspan=1)
ax1  = plt.subplot2grid((6,1), (5,0), rowspan=1, colspan=1)
ax1.plot(df.index, df['Adj Close'])
ax1.plot(df.index, df['100ma'])
ax2.bar(df.index, df['Volume'])
plt.show()
```

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve], such that people can reproduce your problem.

Comment: 'Adj Close' is not a column in your dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Key Error:'Adj Close' is the answer to your problem

A KeyError generally means the key doesn't exist. So, are you sure the path key exists?

From the official python docs:

exception KeyError

Raised when a mapping (dictionary) key is not found in the set of existing keys.

For example:

```
mydict = {'a':'1','b':'2'}
mydict['a']
'1'
mydict['c']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'c'
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment. I wanted to ask which library would include Adj Close. Also great example.

Comment: 'adj close' is simply a a header value in the dataframe or rather a key. your attempting to make one column in the frame equal another column that doesnt exist. I dont think your looking for another library I think your looking for another column. you should print your df and inspect what headers are there to see what ones you would like to operate on.

Comment: print df.head prior to your reference to 'adj close' to see what is there. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Just replace Adj close column with close column because in morningstar use close column as adj close

```
df['100mma'] = df['Adj Close'].rolling(window=100, min_periods=0).mean()
```

replace with

```
df['100mma'] = df['Close'].rolling(window=100, min_periods=0).mean()
```